# Qt Quick parent, not the same as the 'id' of the parent

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2

I'm playing a bit with `Qt Quick` and I wanted to create a title bar for my application. So I inherited `QQuickPaintedItem`, painted a bit on it, and wanted to use it as a title bar for my `Window`. I'm using `Qt 5.7`. This succeeded but only to a certain extent; I'll explain more after the code.

Here is how I did it:

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

#include "mycustomtitlebar.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    qmlRegisterType<MyCustomTitleBar>("my.custom.lib", 1, 0, "MyCustomTitleBar");

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    return app.exec();
}
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import my.custom.lib 1.0

Window {
    id: wnd
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    MyCustomTitleBar {
        id: titleBar
        anchors.top: parent.top
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.right: parent.right
        height: 100
        hostWidget: wnd
    }

    Rectangle {
        color: "beige"
        anchors.top: titleBar.bottom
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.right: parent.right
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
    }
}
```

**mycustomtitlebar.h**

```
#ifndef MYCUSTOMTITLEBAR_H
#define MYCUSTOMTITLEBAR_H

#include <QQuickPaintedItem>
#include <QPoint>

class MyCustomTitleBar : public QQuickPaintedItem
{
    Q_OBJECT

    Q_PROPERTY(QWindow *hostWidget READ hostWidget WRITE setHostWidget)

public:
    MyCustomTitleBar(QQuickItem *parent = 0);

protected:
    virtual void paint(QPainter *pPainter) Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;
    virtual void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *pEvent) Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;
    virtual void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *pEvent) Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;
    virtual void mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *pEvent) Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;

private:
    QWindow *hostWidget() const;
    void setHostWidget(QWindow *pHostWidget);

private:
    QWindow *m_pHostWidget;
    QPoint m_initialMousePosition;
    bool m_leftMouseButtonPressed;
};

#endif // MYCUSTOMTITLEBAR_H
```

**mycustomtitlebar.cpp**

```
#include "mycustomtitlebar.h"

#include <QPainter>
#include <QDragMoveEvent>
#include <QWindow>

MyCustomTitleBar::MyCustomTitleBar(QQuickItem *parent)
    : QQuickPaintedItem(parent),
      m_leftMouseButtonPressed(false),
      m_pHostWidget(Q_NULLPTR)
{
    setAcceptedMouseButtons(Qt::AllButtons);
}

void MyCustomTitleBar::paint(QPainter *pPainter)
{
    // Dummy drawing...
    const QRect myRect(10, 10, width() - 20, height() - 20);
    qDebug() << myRect;
    pPainter->drawRect(myRect);
}

void MyCustomTitleBar::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *pEvent)
{
    m_leftMouseButtonPressed = true;
    m_initialMousePosition = pEvent->pos();
}

void MyCustomTitleBar::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *pEvent)
{
    if (m_leftMouseButtonPressed) {
        if (!m_pHostWidget) {
            qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << "Host widget not set. Please set host widget";
            return;
        }

        const QPoint newMousePosition = pEvent->pos() - m_initialMousePosition + m_pHostWidget->position();
        m_pHostWidget->setPosition(newMousePosition);
    }

    QQuickPaintedItem::mouseMoveEvent(pEvent);
}

void MyCustomTitleBar::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *pEvent)
{
    m_leftMouseButtonPressed = false;
}

QWindow *MyCustomTitleBar::hostWidget() const
{
    return m_pHostWidget;
}

void MyCustomTitleBar::setHostWidget(QWindow *pHostWidget)
{
    m_pHostWidget = pHostWidget;
}
```

Now this code works perfectly, I run the application and I am able to click on the title bar and drag, and the whole window moves where I want it to.

**BUT**, here is the problem: if I change `hostWidget: wnd` to `hostWidget: parent` it doesn't work anymore. Can anyone explain why? Because `wnd` is the `parent`, after all.

P.S.

I also get this very strange error notification from `Qt Creator` but the code compiles and runs fine:
[image]

Why?...

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38555176/qml-referencing-root-window-by-parent-reference-is-unreliable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **But here is the problem: *if I change `hostWidget: wnd` to `hostWidget: parent`
>   it doesn't work anymore.* Can anyone explain why? Because `wnd` is the `parent`
>   after all.**

1. [Window QML type](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-window-window.html) instantiates [`QQuickWindow`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickwindow.html).
2. [`QQuickWindow`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickwindow.html) does not inherit from [`QQuickItem`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickitem.html).
3. Instead it contains a [`QQuickItem`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickitem.html) element accessible through its [`contentItem()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickwindow.html#contentItem-prop) function.
4. [`parent`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickitem.html#parent-prop) property refers to a `QQuickItem` object.

Therefore in your example `titleBar.parent` refers to an element of `wnd` rather than `wnd` itself.

If an attempt is made internally to dynamically cast `titleBar.parent` to `QWindow*` before calling `MyCustomTitleBar::setHostWidget()` it fails because of (2) above (in that case, you should see a corresponding error in the console).

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer! I already tried that, but the behavior is this:
http://im2.ezgif.com/tmp/ezgif-1248938156.gif. Which is also strange. This means that `parent` is not quite the window...idk how it's built under the hood.

Comment: @JacobKrieg I consulted the Qt documentation and changed my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Because `titleBar.parent` is not `wnd`, but `wnd.contentItem` instead. That's why you find its `parent` is not `wnd`.

**Why `wnd.contentItem` instead of `wnd` ?**

Generally, any item will become the `parent` of all subitems it encloses, but it's not the case for `Window`.

The problem here, is that the type of `parent` property is `Item`. Sadly, `Window` does not inherit from `Item`. Thus, a `Window` should contain a real `Item` to be the `parent` of all its children. That's what `Window.contentItem` is used for.